# Getting a please try again later in Paypal Embedded Payments

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

Paypal embedded payments were working just fine on [Instimage](https://www.instimage.com) until they were not.

Getting no error code and nothing in the console to help with debugging the problem.

What could be the problem?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is actually no solution to this problem.

Paypal told me they return this error when the seller who is set as primary receiver of the transaction has a negative balance.
Understandably, there is no way of checking the primary receiver's balance without permission.

In my opinion, there should at least be an API endpoint allowing marketplaces to check if a user can be a primary receiver.

Comment: From the moment the transaction is happening, the primary receiver is transferred money to his/her account, so it should have the amount necessary for the second receiver. Paypal API needs a quick fix...